# Firebase database count number of child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get first the number of children (if any). Then I want to add 1 to number of children, so the added children will be +1 from the existing.

[image: firebase database]

So when I add new question, II want to add number 3. But I get it added as number 1 and it updates the existing number.

```
    int count = 0;
 public void addQuestion(View view) {
     mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Questions");
       count = count + 1;
        String nr = String.valueOf(count);
        GetData getdata = new GetData(qs, A, B, C, correct);
        mRef.child(nr).setValue(getdata);
        Toast.makeText(AdminPanel.this, "Adding question...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared read data from Firebase yet. Did you try any of these? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bandroid%5D+count+children I'd recommend using a [`transaction()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for this - or even better: avoid depending on a children count altogether, since it hurts scalability and won't work when a user is offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the push function and it will generate a unique key, so you don't have to worry about giving then unique numbers.
mRef.push();

you can also get the key that was generated if you need it,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push

or just retrieve all the children (your questions) when needed.

I suggest you read the documentation, I found there all the information I needed.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow & thanks for contributing.  Take a look at 'Help' at the top right of the answer window for code formatting (`mRef.push()`) and displaying links efficiently.